# Prove that, if $p \in \mathbb{N}, p>5$, p prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Prove this:

**Hypothesis**

Let $p \in \mathbb{N}, p>5$, p prime so that $p | (2^q + 3^q)$ where $q \in \mathbb{N}$, $q$ prime.

**Conclusion**

$p>q$

No idea how to start...

Comment: Exactly which part of this is the claim to be proved? That $p|(2^q+3^q)$?

Comment: @BunsOfWrath I didn't see it immediately either: that then $p > q$.

Comment: $p \mid (2^q + 3^q)$ means $2^q + 3^q \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, or $3^q \equiv - 2^q \pmod{p}$. Now let $m = \frac{p+1}{2}$.

Comment: @BunsOfWrath I've re-written the problem for better clarity.

Comment: Nice problem.  I can't resist pointing out the conclusion gives another proof for the infinitude of primes:  For any odd $q\gt1$ (prime or not), $2^q+3^q\equiv3$ mod $8$, so $2^q+3^q$ is not purely a power of $5$, so it's divisible by *some* prime $p\gt5$.  So if $q$ is a prime, there is another prime beyond it.

Comment: There is an answer (which is the "obvious" answer) here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h612974p3646081

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The case $q=2$ is obvious. So suppose that $q$ is an odd prime.

If $p$ divides $2^q+3^q$, then $3^q\equiv (-2)^q\pmod{p}$. Since $p\ne 2$, multiplying through by the inverse $a$ of $-2$ modulo $p$, we get $(3a)^q\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. So the order of $3a$ modulo $p$ divides $q$. Since $q$ is prime, the order is $1$ or $q$.

If $3a\not\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, then $3a$ has order $q$. Thus $q$ divides $p-1$, and therefore $q\lt p$.

Under what conditions is $3a\equiv 1\pmod{p}$? We must have that $3\equiv -2\pmod{p}$, meaning that $p=5$.

Comment: It's $3^q \equiv - (2^q)$. For $q = 2$ that makes a difference.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks, I am now mentioning $q=2$ separately.

Comment: @André Nicolas Beautiful solution

Comment: Where exactly do you use the assumption that $q$ is prime?

Comment: @EugenCovaci: Well, really a tiny variant of the old Fermat result that if $p$ divides $2^q-1$ then $p\gt q$, indeed $p\ge 2q+1$.

Comment: @BarryCipra: The orrder of $3a$ is a divisor of $q$, and it is not $1$. So the order must be $q$, and therefore $q$ divides $p-1$. If $q$ were composite, we could not conclude that $3a$ has order $q$, it could be a non-trivial divisor of $q$.

Comment: very nice solution.  sometimes a bit of exploration of consequences just works.